# File upload API on EC2 with ELB and S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, architecture, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, amazon-elb

I am developing app server with NodeJS and AWS.

I am setting up the server environment with ELB and EC2s.

I am using ELB as load balancer and attached several app server EC2 instances to it.

And one EC2 instance is used for MongoDB.

My question is about request including file upload.

I think uploaded file should not be in app server (EC2 instance), so I will try to save uploaded files in S3 and allow app servers (EC2 instances) to access it.

The rough solution is that if app servers accept a file from client, move it to S3 and delete the file on the app server.

But then it will cause some performance loss and I don't feel it's a clean way.

Is this a best way? or there is another way to solve it.

I think it's best way to upload file to S3.

But file is uploaded with other data. (For example, profile upload - name: String, age: Number, profileImage: File)

I need to process other data on app server, so client should not upload to S3 directly.

Is there any better idea?

Please save me.

P.S: Please let me know if you cannot understand my expression because I am not native. If so, I will add some explanation for it with my best!

Answer (score 0):

You can directly upload to S3 using temporary credentials that allow the end user to write to you bucket.

There is a good article with detailed code for doing exactly what you are trying to do with node.js [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-node).

Answers that refer to external links are frowned upon on SO, so in a nutshell:

- include the aws sdk in your application
- provide it with appropriate credentials
- use those credentials to generate a signed URL with a short lifespan
- provide the end user with the signed URL they can then use to upload, preferably asynchronously with progress feedback

Comment: Thanks @chris. I'm trying to solve the problem with your answer but there's an another problem. I succeeded in getting pre-signed url and I can upload image to S3 directly from browser(I'm testing with post-man: google-chrome extension). But the every uploaded image file is broken. The file was uploaded and its bytes is same as original (I didn't check strictly). But after downloading the image file and executing, I got message - file cannot open. It's broken or unrecognized file format. (I uploaded file png and jpeg). Any solution for me? I struggle with this for 2days long.